# Cannot get plot and day wise date for variables by calling from excel sheet using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot geom_col for two variables, which I am calling from an excel sheet.  Data is in a time-series format.

This is my data set. I want to plot both variable 'Johor' and 'TCK' in one bar for all dates.

```
head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 33
  date       Johor   TCJ Kedah  TCKe Kelantan TCKlntn Melaka  TCMk N.Sembilan  TCN9 Pahang
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2020-01-25     1     1     0     0        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
2 2020-01-26     0     1     0     0        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
3 2020-01-27     0     1     0     0        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
4 2020-01-28     1     2     1     1        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
5 2020-01-29     0     2     0     1        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
6 2020-01-30     1     3     0     1        0       0      0     0          0     0      0
```

This is my code for ggplot2

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=date, y=Johor, col=c(TCJ+Johor), group=c(TCJ+Johor)))+ 
  geom_col(aes(fill=c(TCJ+Johor)),width=0.5
  )+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=15, vjust=0.4)) +
  labs(title="",
       subtitle="")
```

I also want to have all dates in x lab, but for me know I can only have month [image]

Required plot output.

[image: My expectation plot should be like as follows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the stacked bar chart:

It looks like you need to put your data set in long format (and after that filter for TCJ and Johor):

```
library("tidyverse")     
df2 %>%
      pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>%
      filter(name %in% c("Johor", "TCJ")) %>%
      ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = name)) +
      geom_col(position = "stack")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was avoiding to convert data set in long format.  I there any function from where I can directly convert my existing data set to long dataset format.

Comment: I would look into pivot_longer() , but perhaps I misunderstood your question